# In a Firefox extension, how can I copy rich text/links to the clipboard?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

Specifically, I want to copy a link (with text and location) and then to be able to paste it, e.g., into Word as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dig around inside [Download of the Day: AutoCopy Firefox extension](http://lifehacker.com/software/firefox/download-of-the-day-autocopy-firefox-extension-177806.php) or [Clipboard-Save-As 1.0.4](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1478)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. Meanwhile, you've a typo in the second link. It should be https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1478

Answer (score 7):

Here's the actual code:

```
var richText = "<a href=\"" + gContextMenu.linkURL + "\">" + gContextMenu.linkText() + "</a>";
var xfer = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/transferable;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITransferable);
xfer.addDataFlavor("text/html");

var htmlString = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);
htmlString.data = richText;
xfer.setTransferData("text/html", htmlString, richText.length * 2);

var clipboard = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboard;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard);
clipboard.setData(xfer, null, Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard.kGlobalClipboard);
```

It is also recommended to create another `Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString`, whose data is plain text, and add it to the same `xfer` as `text/unicode`