# Firefox Extension that copies HTML link to current web page to clipboard and not just the URL

Tags: firefox, key-bindings, browser-automation, clipboard-interaction

## The Situation

I need to automate the copying of a HTML link to the current page that
is viewed in the current Firefox Tab into other WYSIWYG editors. This
is not the same as copying just the plain-text of the URL, nor is it
the same as pasting just the plain-text of the web pages title. This
is also not the same thing as navigating to some other web page that
has the HTML link to the page of interest, selecting the text with the
mouse cursor, and typing CTRL-C to copy it into the current operating
systems clipboard (both Linux and Windows, should not make any
difference).  Only the update to the clipboard is to be automated; the
pasting from the clipboard into the target application will be done
manually.

The desired [use case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case) is as follows:

1. The user browses to any web page from within Firefox.
2. The user types some user-specified key sequence that is not
   in conflict with standard Firefox built-in key bindings.
3. Firefox will then do only part of what [Copy Link Bookmarklet](http://www.2ality.com/2011/05/copy-link-bookmarklet.html)
   does: Instead of opening up a new separate window/tab and
   constructing and rendering the HTML for the link, and then
   requiring the user to waste motion in selecting and copying the
   link into the clipboard, the extension will then format the HTML
   itself and copy that into the clipboard directly.
4. The user then selects any of the targets described below and
   types CTRL-V to paste the formatted text.
5. The user then sees the link as a link in that target area, and does
   *not* see anything literal like `http://...`

For example, if the webpage browsed to was http://www.google.com, and
the user clicked the user-defined key sequence, and if the user pasted
it into some Google Document, what they would see in that document is
*not* `http://www.google.com` nor would they see `Google`, but instead
would see what you would see when you read this in StackOverflow in a
web browser: [Google](http://www.google.com)

Now, there are Firefox extensions and bookmarklets that come close,
but they all involve no net reduction in mouse motion and/or key press
overhead, which is the most time-wasting aspect of this frequently
occuring [use case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case).  My searches for an existing extension turned
up nothing that exactly meets my needs (see Research section
below). Therefore, I think I may need to roll my own extension (or
modify an existing one), unless someone can point me to an existing
extension that provides this functionality.

The extension I have in mind should work in Firefox version 11 or
greater running on either Linux or any version of Windows. Only
Firefox and a suitable Firefox extension should be needed, and not any
other special software.

Targets of the paste should be:

1. GMail compose text areas
2. Google Documents
3. Microsoft Word documents
4. Microsoft Outlook compose text areas.
5. Any other WYSIWYG editor such as the Blogger post editor.
6. Notepad (in which case it is the web page title that is pasted only
   and not the URL, or both the web page title and URL as separate
   plaintext; either way).

About user-specified key bindings: If there was an extension already
that did the above but without providing the ability to bind a
keybinding to it, then I would expect to be able to use the [keyconfig
extension](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension) extension to handle that aspect. Actually, that might
even be preferable; I don't know yet.

## Research

Below are approaches I investigated that came close to what I want,
but did not exactly meet the need:

1. Hacking on [Copy Link Bookmarklet](http://www.2ality.com/2011/05/copy-link-bookmarklet.html) won't work because, from what I can tell, there is no way to update the OS's clipboard from a bookmarklet, hence why I think that a Firefox extension is required.
2. [In a Firefox extension, how can I copy rich text / links to the clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218462/in-a-firefox-extension-how-can-i-copy-rich-text-links-to-the-clipboard)
3. [3 FireFox Addons to Easier Copy Links and Anchor Texts](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/3-firefox-addons-to-easier-copy-links-and-anchor-texts/26742/) -- None of the extensions listed do what I want because they force you to use the right mouse button and navigate down one or two levels of context menu, which is wasted motion.
4. [Copy Link Text (CoLT)](http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/colt/) -- CoLT also supports copying a hyperlink and it’s associated text as a rich-text formatted link, however it does not include a default keybinding. It looks like [someone](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=11852117#p11852117) else is attempting to tie keyconfig to CoLT, which might be an option as a solution.
5. [Copy URL Plus](http://copyurlplus.mozdev.org/index.html) -- Looks like it has the copy-to-clipboard logic, but doesn't look like it has been maintained since Firefox 1.x timeframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question:

[image] The `CTRL-SHIFT-F11` binding will silently stop working if both [keysnail](https://github.com/mooz/keysnail/wiki%20keysnail) and [keyconfig](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension) are installed into the same Firefox browser. The fix for me was to simply uninstall [keysnail](https://github.com/mooz/keysnail/wiki%20keysnail) as I don't use it.

I did not actually need to write my own Firefox extension, but I did
need to scrape out a bit of code that copies the richtext link from
the [Copy Link Text (CoLT)](http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/colt/) extension and apply it directly as a
binding into the [keyconfig](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension) extension as follows:

1. Install the [keyconfig](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension) extension.
2. Restart Firefox.
3. After Firefox loads up, type `CTRL-SHIFT-F12` to bring up the [keyconfig](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension) configuration menu.
4. On the bottom of the page, click on the **Add a new key** button.
5. In the **Name** field, type in some suitable name such as `Copy Rich Text Link to Current Page`.
6. Type in the following chunk of Javascript code (This code I carved
   out of the `objCoLT.CopyBoth` function inside the `content/colt.js`
   file inside the [Copy Link Text (CoLT)](http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/colt/) extension):

   ```
   var url = content.document.location.href;
   var text = content.document.title;

   // Use the users selection instead of the title if text is selected:
   var selection = document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow.getSelection().toString();
   if (selection != "")
   {
       text = selection;
   }

   var richText = "<a href=\"" + url + "\">" + text + "</a>";

   var xfer = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/transferable;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITransferable);
   xfer.addDataFlavor("text/html");

   var htmlString = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);
   htmlString.data = richText;
   xfer.setTransferData("text/html", htmlString, richText.length * 2);

   var clipboard = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboard;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard);
   clipboard.setData(xfer, null, Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard.kGlobalClipboard);
   ```
7. Click Ok.
8. Back in the main Keyconfig dialog, `<disabled>` should be shown in the text field to the left of the **Apply** button.
9. Click in that text field, and type the keybinding you want to associate with it, such as `CTRL-SHIFT-F11`.
10. Click the **Apply** button.
11. Click the **Close** button to close the Keyconfig configuration dialog box.

To test this out, proceed as follows:

1. In Firefox, navigate to some arbitrary page.
2. Type in `CTRL-SHIFT-F11` (or whatever keybinding you chose above).
3. Notice that no dialog boxes popup; that is intentional.
4. Open up Google Documents, and Create a new document.
5. Click in the new document, and type `CTRL-V`.
6. You should see the HTML/rich-text form of the link pasted in.
7. Click on the link and then click on the URL to the left of `Change`.
8. The browser should open up the original page corresponding to that URL.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to copy URL as HTML with the following bookmark:

```js
javascript: navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ ["text/html"]: new Blob([`<a href="${document.location.href}">${document.title}</a>`], { type: "text/html" }) })]);
```

Unfortunately in firefox the [Clipboard write API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write#browser_compatibility) still requires to set `thedom.events.asyncClipboard.clipboardItem` to `true` in about:config.

Comment: Fabulous – this works nicely for me, thanks! I was trying to do the same thing in Greasemonkey, and couldn't understand why it didn't work – I think Greasemonkey's access to the APIs is restricted.

Comment: This has just stopped working in FF 102. It seems FF now requires the `clipboard-write` permission, but does not support the `clipboard-write` permission.

Answer (score 2):

Several extensions exist that offer copying of title and URL but few seem to support Rich Text creation. The key is that the copied text needs to be **formatted in html** with a `href` *and* it needs to be copied as a **text/html** type.

The extension I went with in the end is [CopyTabTitleUrl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/copytabtitleurl/?utm_content=addons-manager-reviews-link&utm_medium=firefox-browser&utm_source=firefox-browser). ([GitHub](https://github.com/k08045kk/CopyTabTitleUrl)) It supports both requirements and also has a keybind feature along with a toolbar button that can also function as a single-click copy.

Set the **Format** option to:

```
<a href="${url}">${title}</a>
```

Then Activate **Extended Mode** and make sure to check the "**Copy in text/html format**" option in Other. After that, using the format copy, the result can be correctly pasted into Office applications. And Stack Exchange evidently as the links above were created by the add-on.

Note that the Edge implementation of URL copying seems to be somewhat different still. With a default plaintext paste, Edge will just paste in the URL while this approach will of course paste unformatted HTML. But it's close enough.

Comment: indeed, it seems more reliable than the bookmarklet :-)

Comment: @eddygeek First thing I tried here but wouldn't work on my FF version sadly. :)